# python flask - how can i make more space between body elements

Tags: html, css

How can i make space between body elements becuse currently my body elements stick together while i want to make more space between them. Any idea how to do it?

This is my code:

```
 <body>
<center>
    <ul>
        <img src= 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KzsnZEOFwcLfeNI6MBaAjK5_wca3NKmttsV7X7RxmH2HjomcuONuBj1rSEBdfQSeJ6M' style= 'width:120px;height:100px;'>
    
        <h3><p style="color:white ">Youtube to MP4 converter</p></h3>

        <form method = 'POST'>
            <input name = 'input' type= 'text' placeholder = 'Insert video link here:' >
        </form>

        <h3><p style="color:white ">Best Youtube to MP4 converter</p></h3>
    </ul>
</center>

</body>
```

and here is my body:

```
body {
        background: url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1567666.png'); 
        display: compact; 
        background-size: 100%;" 
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: One way is to add `div` tags, where the `height` is specified to the separation height you require; which can be done via a central CSS class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest but not most efective solution is just by adding a cuple of empty `<p></p>` or `<h1></h1>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

For now try a simple solution as add `<br/>` or `<p></p>` between the elements

Answer (score -2):

you could simply try to add 
 HTML Tags between your segments.
So instead of:

```
 <body>
<center>
    <ul>
        <img src= 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KzsnZEOFwcLfeNI6MBaAjK5_wca3NKmttsV7X7RxmH2HjomcuONuBj1rSEBdfQSeJ6M' style= 'width:120px;height:100px;'>
    
        <h3><p style="color:white ">Youtube to MP4 converter</p></h3>

        <form method = 'POST'>
            <input name = 'input' type= 'text' placeholder = 'Insert video link here:' >
        </form>

        <h3><p style="color:white ">Best Youtube to MP4 converter</p></h3>
    </ul>
</center>

</body>
```

you can insert

```
 <body>
<center>
    <ul>
        <img src= 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/KzsnZEOFwcLfeNI6MBaAjK5_wca3NKmttsV7X7RxmH2HjomcuONuBj1rSEBdfQSeJ6M' style= 'width:120px;height:100px;'>
    <br>
        <h3><p style="color:white ">Youtube to MP4 converter</p></h3>

        <form method = 'POST'>
            <input name = 'input' type= 'text' placeholder = 'Insert video link here:' >
        </form>
<br>
        <h3><p style="color:white ">Best Youtube to MP4 converter</p></h3>
    </ul>
</center>
<br>
</body>
```

Comment: And how do i do that?